# Background image in lock screen on Lollipop

Tags: settings, lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop, images, wallpaper

Upgrading to Lollipop, at some point the lock screen got a background image (see file attached). I never selected such image, and I can't find how to change in in the new settings menu :-/

Comment: What "file attached" are you referring to?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to attache the image, find it at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/608222/tmp/2014-11-30%2020.54.21.png

Comment: the issue is I have no idea where that image came from...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Last but not least, the Lollipop lock screen shows full-screen still
>   images from multimedia content being played from the device -- so you
>   might see a graphic from a TV show or cover art from an album,
>   depending on what you're streaming. In my experience, however, the
>   images don't seem to clear properly when the content is no longer
>   being played. I frequently saw images from a show I had stopped
>   streaming long ago -- both when something different was being streamed
>   and when the streaming app was no longer even active.

Found at [Android 5.0 deep-dive review: Exploring Lollipop's many layers](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2847459/android-5-0-deep-dive-review-exploring-lollipops-many-layers.html)

In order to fix it I launched some streaming audio and locked the screen to verify the image changed.  Then I unlocked the screen and stopped the stream.  Locked the screen and the image was set back to default wallpaper.

Comment: OK, got the source of the issue, in mi case [TuneIn Radio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tunein.player&hl=en). This is a very annoying _feature_...

Comment: But in my case I can't get rid of the image... no that easy.

Comment: TuneIn Radio is what I was using as well and on a Nexus7.  Suggest trying to clear it by using another steaming service.

Comment: Is there no way to disable this feature altogether? I don't want cover art on my lock screen. I am stuck with the cover of the audio book I am currently listening to on Audible. The book is great, but its cover is downright ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. TuneIn radio is indeed the culprit. In order to get rid of it do the following:

1. Launch TuneIn
2. Play any channel
3. Lock your screen
4. Go to lock screen
5. Stop TuneIn from the lock screen (press square stop button on displayed widget).
6. Background reverts to normal. Done!

Comment: At step 5, launch any streaming app of your choice. I uninstalled TuneIn and installed the BBC radio player instead, which reset the unlock screen background for me.

Answer (score 1):

all right, i got exact same issue as you described. i was listening the TunelIn Radio then i got the cover of the radio show on the screen lock background. i did the following to get rid of the cover photo:
open any app (not build in by Google) on your device, lock the screen before the app is full running, then unlock , the lock screen background should back to the same as your wallpaper background.  may need try few times to make it work. good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

In lollipop stock, there is no built-in setting that lets you set a fixed lock screen wallpaper that is different from the normal home screen wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have root access, then this is how you do it.

1. Navigate to `/data/system/users/0/`
2. Here you will find the file `keyguard_wallpaper`.

Deleting it will set your lockscreen wallpaper to reflect your main wallpaper.

Comment: Are you using CyanogenMod?

Comment: Yes I'm currently using cm13.